# what is the safe volts for truck battery?

Tags: battery, voltage

I have a device for checking battery volts but I don't know what is the acceptable limit for the battery volts

Answer (score 1):

If it is a lead acid battery like the ones in cars you should read around 13.8V (2.25V to 2.3V per cell) with the engine running. Most trucks use a 24V system so you have to multiply it by two, which gives 27.6V. However you have to check if your truck uses two 12v battery or one 24v battery if the prior you should read 13.8V between the leads of each battery

Comment: Never seen a single 24v battrry on a truck - always two 12v in series... Some vehicles with two batteries have them in parallel to give more capacity at 12v.